# How to change the dynamic information in data driven pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, data-driven-pages

[image]

I want to ask one question about data driven pages.

I plan to create data driven pages to show each parish’s information in Louisiana. Followed is the template I am going to use. I downloaded it from ATSDR.
See there is Demographic Statistics in the plate? I wish the statistics could change when the county changes.
For example, when the map demonstrates county A, county A’s information would appear; while in next page, the map showed county B, and county B’s information come out.
I tried to insert dynamic elements, but it failed. Because dynamic elements only include page number, date, etc.
Is there anyone know how to deal with that? If you need further information, please let me know.

Comment: please edit the question with your version of arcmap. there are quite a few differences in DDP across the versions. this is the section of esri help that you can find DDP in.   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/What_are_Data_Driven_Pages/00s90000003m000000/ Look just below this section also for creating map books.

Comment: For this I would use what I call pseudo dynamic text - definitely possible but non-trivial

Comment: @JieLi What version of ArcMap are you using?

Comment: @SaraBarnes, I am using Arcmap 10.2.2.Thank you

Comment: @BradNesom 
 
 
Brad Nesom, thank you for your help. I read the related chapters in the website, but it does not mentioned my concerns. It only talked about the dynamic elements, include date, time, page number, etc. What I want is the whole demographic statistics. I am thinking I should use python

Comment: @PolyGeo, thank you for help. I am quite interested in the pseudo dynamic text. I do some research on the website, but still confused. Do you need to use Python? Thank you again

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In ArcMap 10.2 and above, you can use Data Driven Pages so that your attribute information (such as the demographic text listed above) changes when the page changes.

**You can display any attribute in your attribute table as dynamic text in the map.**  If the attributes you want to display are not in your feature class, consider doing a join from a table with the attributes into your feature class.

To do this, on the Data Driven Pages toolbar, click on "Page Text" and choose "Data Driven Page Attribute."  In the pop-up window that appears, use the drop down menu to choose the field you want to display.
[image]

This will insert a text box in your map that contains text something like this:

```
<dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="AREA_SQ_MI" domainlookup="true"/>
```

To recreate the statistics like they are in your sample image, you can position the text boxes with the statistics and other text boxes accordingly.  In my example, I kept each piece of text in its own text box and used the Align and Distribute tools to line them up.  I used a hollow rectangle to make my outline.  Here is a screenshot with everything selected, so you can see all of the text box borders and the rectangle border.

(You could combine the dynamic text code all into one text box but I find the spacing is easier this way.)
[image]

Here is a quick sample I did to show that it works (also showing a snapshot of the attribute table).
[image]

Comment: That is awesome.  Thanks for sharing this, I had no idea this functionality was available with 10.2.

Comment: or rather than doing a join. I add page name fields to most of my other data. Then using the page definition (found on the query definition tab in properties) you can enable match or don't match. With this functionality there is quite a bit you can do.

Comment: This functionality has been available in all versions since 10.0. At 10.0, the syntax was: <dyn type="page" property="AREA_SQ_MI"/>. At 10.1, it was the same as 10.2: <dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="AREA_SQ_MI" domainlookup="true"/>

Comment: @BradNesom I wasn't familiar with the Page Definition, so I looked it up.  I can see how it will only display features that match the area you are looking at, but how will that help to display the dynamic text attributes for each layer?  Maybe I missed what you were trying to say.

Comment: @SaraBarnes That is awesome! I have another question. take your case as an example, I want to add several attributes as the dynamic text. so you mean I should add several text boxes accordingly? I wish I could put all the attributes information in one boxes, just like you did. How to do that. Thank you so much! you give me a great help:)

Comment: @JieLi The way I created my example was by adding multiple text boxes and then arranging them.  You could also copy all of the dynamic text code into one text box, but I think the spacing will be easier if you leave it in separate text boxes and arrange them accordingly.  I will add another picture in my answer to show all of the text boxes and rectangle that I used to make it.  You can use the Align and Distribute tools to make things line up nicely.

Comment: @SaraBarnes Thank you so much!Have a good weekend^_^

Comment: @JieLi You're welcome - glad it helped!

Comment: If your papge is named mystate. And your data has mystate. The dynanic data can display data that matches or doesnt match (your choice) by enabling the page definition