# How to display dynamic text from a joined table attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.4, dynamic-text

I'm using ArcMap 10.4 with dynamic pages setup. Everything I've found online says that if you join a table to the index layer you should be able to add the data from one of the table's fields via dynamic text (example: [How to change the dynamic information in data driven pages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126334/how-to-change-the-dynamic-information-in-data-driven-pages)). Nothing is working.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I can't just add a field to the index since it's used in a bunch of other files and I can't get access to unlock it. The join works fine, I can see the attributes in the attribute table of the index layer, but no joy on getting them into dynamic text in anyway.

currently using: `<dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="CONCEPT_NAME" domainlookup="true" />`

This just yields a text box saying [EMPTY]

Comment: "Everything I've found online says..." - can you include some links?

Comment: Are you using Data Driven Pages?

Comment: Try to make query on the join table and see how field called e.g jtable:concept.   Perhaps use this naming

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't set up data driven pages with your index layer, then your dynamic text will display `[EMPTY]`.

To make the dynamic text display the correct value, Data Driven Pages need to be set up using your index layer.  That is the only way for the dynamic text to display the correct attribute from the current index record.

Once you have Data Driven Pages set up correctly, your code should work fine as is (it did in my test).  If not, you may need to add the join table name to your field name as @FelixIP has commented e.g. `jointbl.CONCEPT_NAME` if your join table is called `jointbl`